# Synergy not stopping service completely

Tags: windows, windows-8, services, synergy

I'm using Synergy 1.4.12 (server) on windows 8 pro 64bit.

I'm getting a bug when I try to stop the service. If I click stop in to window or by right-clicking the startup icon, the Synergy service stops BUT synergys.exe remains running, I can still control clients till end the process.

```
DEBUG: start ipc handle data
DEBUG: ipc read: ICMD
DEBUG: finished ipc handle data
DEBUG: new command, elevate=1 command=
DEBUG: adopting new buffer
DEBUG: discarding 1 event(s)
ERROR: ipc connection error, remote host closed
NOTE: connecting to service...
NOTE: connection established
```

What could be causing this error? I have checked and the service IS running before I click stop. After I click stop, the service has stopped but synergy still establishes a connection. 
I believe this error stops the rest of the "stop" command so synergy still believes the service is running.
This connection stops once I end synergys.exe and I get

```
ERROR: ipc connection error, connection refused
NOTE: connecting to service...
```

I'm surprised synergy can work without the service running as long as synerys.exe is around.

Oh I've also installed and reinstalled, removed leftover registries and config files with revo uninstaller. Tried nightly builds too. Oh and this is a fresh install of windows 8 pro.

Edit* I updated my Windows 7 pro and Windows 7 home from synergy 1.4.10 to 1.4.12 and I'm having the same trouble with Windows 7 pro but not home edition. Wonder if it's a bug.

Also, when clicking "Apply" synergy seems to stop the service correctly, both service and synergys.exe/synergyc.exe before restarting with a new config.

Comment: Same issue here...very strange.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the latest version of [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy/). Please update your installation to get the fix.